# How does a boundary operator act on a 2-simplex?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A $ be a 2-simplex with vertices $\{0, 1, 2\} $. I want to show that $\rho_1\circ\rho_2 (A)=0$,  where $\rho $ is the boundary operator. How do I go about doing that?

The major problem that I am facing is that I do not know how to calculate $\rho_1 (0, 2) $. According to the alternating sum rule, this should be $0+2$. Does that even make sense? Shouldn't the boundary operator map a 1-simplex to a difference of two vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the notation I'm familiar with, in which an $n$-simplex is denoted $[v_0,\dots,v_n]$, and the same $n$-simplex with $v_i$ removed is denoted $[v_0,\dots,\hat{v_i},\dots,v_n]$. The boundary operator is
$$\rho_n[v_0,\dots,v_n]=\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i[v_0,\dots,\hat{v_i},\dots,v_n].$$
You seem to claim that $\rho_2[0,2]=[0]+[2]$ because $(-1)^0=(-1)^2=1$. However, once the vertex $1$ has been removed, the vertex $2$ is now in an "even" position - $0$ is the zeroth vertex and $2$ is the first vertex. The "number" or "label" of the vertices have no bearing on the boundary operator (you could call the vertices $a$ and $b$ or "cat" and "dog"), only their positions relative to one another.

The boundary operator applied to $[v_0,v_1]$ gives 
$$\rho_1[v_0,v_1]=(-1)^0[v_1]+(-1)^1[v_1]=[v_1]-[v_0].$$
Applying this to $[v_0,v_1]=[0,2]$ (i.e., $v_0=0$ and $v_1=2$) gives $\rho_1[0,2]=[2]-[0]$. In general, $\rho_1$ applied to a $1$-simplex gives the "end" vertex minus the "start" vertex (so $\rho_1[\text{cat},\text{dog}]=[\text{dog}]-[\text{cat}]$, and so on).